# Set Java environment variable problem on ubuntu

Tags: java, linux

I got a message "No Java virtual machine could be found from your PATH
environment variable.  You must install a VM prior to
running this program." Does anyone know how set up it correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you install Java the Ubuntu way, you won't have to add it to the PATH yourself.

First, install Java from the Ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

There are several other packages: sun-java6-jdk for the JDK, sun-java6-plugin for the browser plug-in etc.

Use Ubuntu's alternatives mechanism to select Sun Java 6 as the default version of Java that you want to use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This will present you with a menu where you can choose which version of Java you want to use by default (you can have multiple Java versions installed at the same time on your system).

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: Note that all the other command-line programs installed with Java and controlled separately and may need to be updated as well.  As per the link, you can do that with the update-java-alternatives command.

Comment: this answer doesnt work on suse or redhat, by the way, when you install from jdk rpms downloaded from oracle.

Answer (score 5):

As the error message says, this looks like you have not set your PATH or JAVA_HOME environment variable correctly.

can you execute java from the command line? Try:

```
$ java -version
```

or

```
$ dpkg -L sun-java6-jre
```

Provided your are using debian or some derivative of it, if the "dpkg ..." command gives you any useful output, you should set the JAVA_HOME to the location of the installation directory, for instance

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.10
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

and you should be able to get java running.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you have the path to your java binaries.

locate javac

This will return a list of all locations matching "java". Look for something like "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.11".

Open /etc/environment with a text editor and add the following. Make sure you set JAVA_HOME to the actual path of the java installation directory you just found:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.11"
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to install this package

> sudo apt-get install sun-java5-bin

also check this

> ```
> > #!/bin/bash
> > # Init Script for j2re
> > #This goes in /etc/profile.d
> > 
> > JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/j2reVERSion
> > PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
> > 
> > export JAVA_HOME PATH
> ```